Where is CurrencyType Metadata for Multicurrency stored in VSCode?
tl;dr - Is CurrencyType metadata available for tracking in VSCode, and if so where is it stored?
I'm working on a project that involves activating multiple currencies in my org. I've been able to locate the Currency.setting-meta.xml file which captures that multiple currencies have been enabled, but I'm not able to find where metadata for the actual CurrencyType metadata is stored. Is this metadata available or does the new currency have to be manually activated in each sandbox and org?

It's not metadata - it's stored as record data in CurrencyType. You can query it in the org and see which are used.
SELECT Id, ConversionRate, DecimalPlaces, IsActive, IsoCode FROM CurrencyType   

You could insert the data into the org as you typically manipulate record data (data loader, cli tool, etc).

I did not expect that, but there you go. Thanks! Marked as the solution.
